# Installation on UEFI fails

Tags: uefi

After installing Elementary (latest version, July 2021) from a USB stick, computer get's UEFI errors when rebooted. The only way to get the installation correct is to disable UEFI and use legacy support, Elementary then works OK. It seems that GRUB is not properly installed/configured, the 1st time installation actually showed a GRUB error. In this same computer I just installed Ubuntu 20 LTS on UEFI and it works w/o issues (Ubuntu and most Linux distros use GRUB, Elementary seems to use GRUB2). My laptop is a Lenovo Idea Pad 5 Flex (end of 2020 model).

Comment: Having the same issue with Dell XPS 15 and the final release of Elementary OS 6.0 (Odin).
The BIOS is configured to UEFI without security. And I getting error following error message: <br/>
`Failed to open \EFI\boot\[?] - Invalid Parameter<br/>
Failed to load image \EFI\boot\[?]: Invalid Parameter <br/>
start_image() return Invalid Paramater`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a dual OS installed, then just go with the Legacy, but if that is not the case, you are advised to partition your driver as GPT before installing any OS then install burn your OS as GPT & UEFI. try this and let me know.

Comment: I already a a separate partition that had Ubuntu, I simply selected the same partition and reformatted. I have done the same thing for other Linux distorsionada, always works, Elementary is the 1st one that doesn't.